# How Could I get the only data from the $form->createView(),

Tags: symfony

I have source code which handles the data after 'post'.

```
$DB = new DataBase();
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($DB)

$request = $this->get('request');
$form->bindRequest($request); //bind post data to form

$form->setName('myname');

return $this->render('AcmeMemberBundle:Default:submit.html.twig',
        array('form' => $form->createView());
```

then in twig

```
{{form_widget(form.name)}}
```

stands for the input form with 'myname' is  inputted by default.

But I want to show only 'myname' without input form.

Can I do this ?

If I can do this ,it is very useful for making submit confirmation page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to the value like this :

`{{ form.name.vars.value }}`

see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-variables-reference

Hope it's helpful.

Best regard.